# titanium tableview font color

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, tableview

How to change the font-color in a TableView. Other elements can be changend with the `color` attribute.

When i run the app on my Android Phone the table is displayed, but the font-color is still grey/white. There are also no table borders. I want to set the color to black.

```
// create an array of anonymous objects
var tbl_data = [
    {title:'Row 1'},
    {title:'Row 2'},
    {title:'Row 3'}
];
// now assign that array to the table's data property to add those objects as rows
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:tbl_data,
    color: '#000000'
});

amountView.add(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Titanium docs; [`TableView`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView) does not have `color` property.

What you can do is create [`TableViewRow`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow) and add them to `TableView`; and finally applying `TableViewRow's` [`color`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-property-color) property. *Example below:*

```
var tableData = [],
    win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

    tableData.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: 'Apples', color : "#000" }));
    tableData.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: 'Bananas', color : "#000" }));
    tableData.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: 'Carrots', color : "#000" }));
    tableData.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: 'Potatoes', color : "#000" }));

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData
});

win.add(table);
win.open();
```

Comment: for providing border color there is a `separatorColor` property for `tableView`.